# ML.NET doesn't support resuming training for ImageClassificationTrainer

Tags: image, ml.net

I want to continue training the model.zip file with more images without retraining from the baseline model from scratch, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible at the moment. ML.NET's `ImageClassificationTrainer` already uses a [pre-trained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.vision.imageclassificationtrainer?view=ml-dotnet#training-algorithm-details) model, so you're using transfer learning to create your model. Any additions would have to be "from scratch" on the pre-trained model.

Also, looking at the [existing trainers that can be re-trained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/retrain-model-ml-net#:%7E:text=ML.NET%20provides%20functionality%20for%20re-training%20models%20using%20learned,time.%20The%20following%20algorithms%20are%20re-trainable%20in%20ML.NET:), the `ImageClassificationTrainer` isn't listed among them.